# I need to do two loops a do/while and a For in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, do-while

I have a task for my JavaScript class that is driving me crazy. This is the task:

> Create a page that requests the name of the members of a club. To this
> end, the Page prompts you for each name and then displays a dialog box
> Asking if you want to continue. Once the user has finished Enter all
> the names the page should show the following data:
>
> - table with the names of the partners in the order they have been inserted.

This is my code:

```
var club = new Array();
var choice=0;
do {
  socio[i] = prompt ("Introduce the name of the person", "");
  choice = prompt("If you don't want to keep going introduce number 1, and if you want to keep going introduce another number");
} while(choice != 1);

for (var i = 0; i < club.length; i++){
  document.write("<table>");
  document.write("<tr>");
  document.write("<td>" + club[i] + "</td>");
  document.write("</tr>");
  document.write("</table>");
}
```

The loop is not reading the `for`. I tried to put inside the `do` statement but it didn't work.

Comment: `"The loop is not reading the for"` - What does that even *mean*?

Comment: when the user insert number 1 to not continue the table doesnt print out.

Comment: @CapitanDuke I see you accepted my answer, but please also see my edited version of it. Your code had simple issues that you could work through with some debugging, so maybe ask your instructor for some help too. No one should expect you to write perfect code straight away, so you need to know how to see the errors in your code that are reported in order to make any progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a number of issues :

- `club` is an empty array, so the for loop has nothing to execute
- you refer to a non-existent variable `socio` with a non-existent index `i`. Maybe you meant to do `club.push(prompt(...))` or something similar?
- using `prompt` and asking for a specific input to end is pretty clunky. `confirm` might be a better option.

With that taken into consideration, here's a cleaned-up version of your code. Note that this is not meant to be the best way of doing this(and it's definitely not how I would do this), but it's just your code cleaned up a little to capture your intent.

https://plnkr.co/edit/JkBiCkZrPY7N3YC2uC6a?p=preview

```
var club = new Array();
var proceed = true;
while(proceed) {
  club.push(prompt ("Enter the name of the person", ""));
  proceed = confirm("Would you like to continue?");
}

for (var i = 0; i < club.length; i++){
  document.write("<table>");
  document.write("<tr>");
  document.write("<td>" + club[i] + "</td>");
  document.write("</tr>");
  document.write("</table>");
}
```

Since this is homework, for further reading you can think about why `document.write` may not be appropriate to use in this case- for example, if I enter `<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg">` as a name instead of something like `Tom` or `Kate`, observe what happens :)

In general, you should learn how to debug your program. I don't know what tools you are using for your class, but if you run the code in a browser, you can press `F12` in most browsers to open a developer console. That will show you errors in your code, for example : 
[image]

It's not expected that you should write syntactically-correct code all the time, so you need to have a way to get feedback that your code has errors. Perhaps ask your classmates or instructor about how to debug your code.